# D3 force layout start takes 5 second to execute

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I use d3 in my project and used force layout in it.

After executing d3 `force.start()` function it takes for 5 seconds to make layout and display content in browser.

[This](http://bl.ocks.org/sathomas/11550728) example uses force layout with 2 nodes only. Simple, right? But it takes long time to load these nodes.

**QUESTION:** Is it normal for this kind of layout or it is a smell of some error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're just misunderstanding the example. It doesn't take 5 seconds to load the nodes. It takes 5 seconds for the layout to cool down (to stabilize).

Initially the nodes are positioned randomly and the `start` event is emitted. Then the force layout goes into a loop where it recalculates the node positions and cools down the layout (by gradually reducing the `alpha` value). For every loop pass there's a `tick` event emitted. Finally, when the layout has stabilized (`alpha` is sufficiently close to zero), the `end` event is emitted.

The code in the example displays nodes only when `end` event is emitted:

```
// We're about to tell the force layout to start its
// calculations. We do, however, want to know when those
// calculations are complete, so before we kick things off
// we'll define a function that we want the layout to call
// once the calculations are done.

force.on('end', function() { ...
```

You can change it to `tick`, as in [this modified example](http://jsfiddle.net/5eaw6yju/), to see the nodes appear instantly. But the nodes will be bouncing around until layout has stabilized.

You can read more about force layout in the [Force Layout documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout). And here's information about [`force.on`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#on).